# What is the best way to get list from sharepoint via c# (office 365)

Tags: list, development

I am trying to get a list out SharePoint (office 365) using c#. What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# and trying to do operations on SharePoint online site you should use the SharePoint online Client component SDK.

Here is a link to download
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Let me know if you are looking for same and need additional info.

Comment: I would also like to add this is the best tutorial I found on caml so far

Comment: http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html